# How does the readLine() has a nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, android

I am confused about the readLine() of the BufferedReader class. I have the following code：

```
BufferedReader ir=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

while(ir.readLine()!=null){
      String tmp=ir.readLine();
      sb.append(tmp);
      if(tmp!=null){
      Log.i("recHtml", tmp);
      }
```

The code works as expected. However, if we remove the

```
        if(tmp!=null){
```

Then the code will get a nullpointerexception for the

```
        Log.i("recHtml", tmp);
```

I am quite confused. I already check this in the while statement, why there is a still a nullpointer error?

Comment: You are reading 2 lines in one cycle

Comment: So you expect to skip every other line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(ir.readLine()!=null){
    //...
}
```

This already reads a line, so when you want to actually obtain the line you checked about you get the next one, instead. In the last case, that's null since there are no other lines left.

The check should actually be done with the `hasNextLine` method, defined for that check:

```
while(ir.hasNextLine()){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the line twice. The second time, you could potentially hit the end of the file and receive a null value. Introduce your `tmp` variable *outside* of the while loop so that you only read it once each time:

```
String tmp = null;
while((tmp = ir.readLine()) !=null){
    sb.append(tmp);
    Log.i("recHtml", tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 2 lines in one cycle.

Change your code to something like this.

```
String tmp= null;
while( (tmp = ir.readLine()) !=null){
      sb.append(tmp);
      Log.i("recHtml", tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah exactly you are reading twice by using the readLine() twice in while loop. First time it read form the 1st readLine in the while loop and again if the control enters the while loop body then with the 2nd readLine() it read the string as null. That is the reason why it is giving null pointer Exception.

Try using readLine() once in the while loop.